# How to present last 7 days if data from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a dynamic data table that includes a date column.

How can I filter on the last 7 days and presenting my results at WW & year?

For example if I have the next date: `2016-06-22 09:00:43.307`, I hope to see it like this: `2016 WW26`.

My data table is (some of it):

```
complete_date            operation_code  step_in_quantity
---------------------------------------------------------
2016-05-03 06:57:18.667  7461            130
2016-05-03 03:35:16.813  7460            166
2016-05-03 07:39:23.010  7461            162
2016-05-04 03:43:44.773  7462            159
2016-05-03 10:27:10.480  7460            160
2016-05-04 08:41:45.693  7461            154
2016-05-05 00:09:48.733  7462            148
2016-05-03 05:09:49.367  7460            21
2016-05-05 01:09:20.667  7461            21
```

In addition how do we see dates that should be from previous year or month? E.g. `3.1.16` --> last 7 days will be from year 2015 at December.

Comment: Can You explain more how did You get that 2016 WW26 ?

Comment: What does WW mean?

Comment: work week

now we at WW26 of 2016 year

Comment: Is 26 a no of work week on year 2016?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear.  Try this and let me know if that is what you are looking for:

```
Select  'WW' + Convert(Char(2), DatePart(WK, '2016-06-22 09:00:43.307')) WeekNum,
        complete_date, operation_code, step_in_quantity
    From TableA
    Where DateDiff(d, complete_date, getdate()) < 8
```

Comment: HI & thanks
 Where DateDiff(d, complete_date, getdate()) < 8   
Is exactly what I search for my last 7 days filter.

Comment: I do not understend how you converted the date data to WW.
You add it to select row can we do it? in not should be after WHERE?

Comment: Using datepart in the select clause gives you the week of the year, which is what I was thinking you were looking for.  In the where clause it is just looking for the past seven days and will not garuntee that it is week 26, you will have to take care that the date parameter is the week ending date.  Otherwise you will need to use other date functions to take a date passed in and match it to a week ending...

Comment: oooo now I understood, I edited my data + query and it looks it works great!! thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try it..I think it is your desire result..

```
Select  'WW' + cast(datepart(month, DATEADD(d,7,complete_date)) as varchar(2)) + ' ' +cast(datepart(year,complete_date) as varchar(4)) result,
        complete_date, operation_code, step_in_quantity
    From Your_table
    ----Where DateDiff(d, complete_date, getdate()) < 8
```

Comment: what the 'd' means? + I tried it but I geeting the next results under results: WWJu2016 ---> I want to get WW05 2016

Comment: ` 'WW  ' + cast( datepart(month,DATEADD(d,7,complete_date)) as `varchar(2)) + cast(datepart(year,complete_date) as varchar(4)) result`